# Getting custom component prop value in Vue app

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a custom checkmark I created.

```
Vue.component('checkle', {
    props: ['crisis'],
    template: '<input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" />',
    mounted: function() {
        var vm = this
        $(this.$el).on('change', function() {
            vm.$emit('change')
        })
    }
})

            <checkle crisis="crisisvalue"
                     v-model="Model"
                     @change="changeLEC()" :disabled="!SomeValue">
            </checkle>
```

As you can see I have a `@change` which is defined in my Vue App. But I don't know how to access my `crisis` prop inside my app. Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: where is changeLEC defined?  It should be part of the `methods:` property

Comment: It is inside of methods, but not the custom component methods, rather the Vue app methods.

Answer (score 0):

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html

You can access props directly by name:

```
@change="changeLEC(crisis)"
```

or `this.crisis` inside `changeLEC`, which should be provided to your component as part of the `methods:` property of your component object.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. `this.crisis` is undefined in the method `changeLEC`. The method is part of my app, not of my component. I did try to change the method to my component but now it just says it isn't defined but it is referenced.

Comment: passing crisis directly should also work fine.  also, don't use arrow functions on the methods definition.  it messes up the `this` binding.  another option is to pass `this` to changeLEC or using `changeLEC.bind(this)`, although I strongly recommend not doing that.  shouldn't you be passing $event?